# UpdateProgress dropdownlist and textbox does't work if Ajaxtoolkit was added and used on content page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Guys I have this weird problem. The UpdateProgress will not work properly if AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET4 was added and use it on the content page(with the master page). It will not show the UpdateProgress if the dropdownlist has changed or the textbox has changed but the submit button is okay.

I have created the project in the zip below, please let me know how to solve this problem.
http://www.sendspace.com/file/eijczf

The UpdateProgress will NOT work if using a master page and AjaxControlToolkit installed
The UpdateProgress will work if no AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET4 installed
The UpdateProgress will work without master page

This has been tested IE8 and Firefox V16.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figure it out. Just set the ClientIDMode="AutoID"